# JSON object parsing using OGNL in struts 2

Tags: json, jsp, struts2, ognl

I have an action class like

```
public class DataProcessor extends ActionSupport{

    private JSONObject object;

    public JSONObject getObject() {
        return object;
    }

    public void setObject(JSONObject object) {
        this.object = object;
    }

    @Override
    public String execute() throws Exception {
        .......
        return SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

My XML mapping is like

```
<package name="default" extends="struts-default" namespace="/">
   <action name="process" class="com.demo.DataProcessor">
      <result type="success">home.jsp</result>
   </action>
</package>
```

on jsp page if i write `<s:property value="object"/>` it prints json data. bt if i write

```
<s:property value="object.name"/>
```

or

```
<s:property value="#object.name"/>
```

or

```
<s:property value="${#object.name}"/>  it is printing nothing.
```

How can i parse json object in jsp page?

Comment: Do you have a json object why do you need to parse it?

Comment: i am getting object like '{name:lalit, mobile:9999999999}' and it is printing in same format. i want to print name and mobile separately.

Comment: What type is your `object`? Is it `org.json.JSONObject`?

Comment: A JSON object isn't a JavaBean, and you can't access it like it is. as Aleksandr says you must use its own access mechanism. It might be easier to convert it on the server side, though. If you only need it in JavaScript then parsing it as Roman says is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to parse JSON you need to retrieve value from it. Assuming that your `object` is `org.json.JSONObject` you can get value from it by calling `get` method and passing key as string.

```
<s:property value="object.get('name')"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can parse JSON using the library function `parseJSON` like in this example

```
<s:textfield id="name" name="name"/>
<s:textfield id="mobile" name="mobile"/>    
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var obj = $.parseJSON('<s:property value="object"/>');
    $("name").val(obj.name);
    $("mobile").val(obj.mobile);
  });
</script>
```

This script will replace the values (if any) from the action bean populated when JSP was rendered. The textfields should be mapped to the action bean correspondingly.